# Show pop-up message after a form is submitted until PHP commmands are executed

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I would like to use a popup message (not necessarily as a new window item), just to inform the user that current page will be refreshed shortly (truly after some background php commands will have been executed.)

I don't want to freeze the execution of php though. I want this message to be shown after a form is submitted  (`if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { ...` for as long as the execution lasts. After php commands are executed, I run `echo ('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;">');` to refresh page after 1 second, but I would like to inform the user that the page will be refreshed shortly and to discourage them from refreshing manually.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned can be achieved through an ajax call like the following sample code. This code should be inside a seperate .js file and included in your page

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    $(".loader").show(); // Show loader or popup message

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               $(".loader").hide();// hide the loader/popup message after the form is submitted

               setTimeout(function(){ // wait 1 second after you get the response
                  location.reload(true); // reload the page
               }, 1000);
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apologies for my ignorance. But could help me understand how exactly should I add this in my html/php file?

Comment: This would be a seperate file. One is the "server side" (your PHP code) and one is the "client side" (your HTML/jQuery). You should learn the difference between server- and clientside.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to do anything... What am I supposed to observe after clicking "submit"?

Comment: @nullgeppetto replace the .loader in the code with whatever text/modal class or id you want to show. In my code I supposed you already have some kind of text in place, something like this 

`<div class="loader">Please be patient while the form is submitting, the page will auto reload once done
</div>`